# Loaded die problem.

Tags: probability

A die is loaded in such a way that the probability that a 6 is thrown is ﬁve times that of any other number, each of them being equally probable. What is the ratio of the probability of obtaining a total of 23  with that of obtaining a total of 24 from four throws.

As the die is loaded, probability of getting a six is 1/2 or 5/10, so the probability of getting any other number a part from six is 1/10.

A total of 23 can be made by the combination (5,6,6,6) and its corresponding 4 arrangements

p1=p(total of 23)= 4 * 5/10*5/10*5/10*1/10

A total of 24 can be made by the combination (6,6,6,6)

p2=p(total of 24) = 5/10*5/10*5/10*5/10

ratio = p1/p2 = 4/5

I found this answer by solving

But the answer given is p1/p2 = 4

So, where I am getting wrong, I could not understand. Please share if anybody got some other workaround for this problem.

Comment: First step: find the probability that a six is rolled.  Find the probability that a five is rolled.  Second step: describe the way or ways that you could get a sum of 24 with four rolls.  Describe the way or ways that you could get a sum of 23 with four rolls.  Third step: Find the probability of getting a sum of 24 with four rolls.  Find the probability of getting a sum of 23 with four rolls.  Final step: Find the ratio desired.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I think you will find Questions receive a more favorable response when you make clear that you have some understanding of the problem statement yourself.  Surely some approach has occurred to you (however tedious or unworkable), and mentions of what you find difficult or interesting about a problem are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- What are the ways that you can make $24$ with four die throws?  How about the ways of throwing $23$?
- What is the probability of throwing a $6$?  If $p_1$ is the probability of throwing a $1$ then the probability of throwing a $6$ is $p_6 = 5p_1$.  Also note that $\sum_{j=1}^6 p_j = 1.$
- From this you can calculate the probability of four independent throws summing to $24$, and then to $23$.